# How to save an image from a base64 string passed through ajax request using c# webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, image, httpresponse

I want to upload an image when i select it from an input file control.
How can i upload it, with async process and refresh the link in the page when finish the upload.

I have already created the ajax request that call a c# WebMethod, but my problem is, how can i pass the image as a json variable to my WebMethod.
I tryied to convert the image to base64 string, but when i send it, iis send me error that the request is invalid.

```
function getBase64(file, cb) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);//outputs random looking characters for the image
        // Return the result in the callback
        cb(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}

var imgbase64="";
function caricaImmagine(inputFile) {

    var _image = $(inputFile)[0].files[0];
    getBase64(_image, function (result) {

        sendData(result);
    });

}

function sendData(data) {
    imgbase64=data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/admin/ajax_handler.aspx/uploadImgVarianti',
        data: "{imgBase64:'"+data+"'}",
        success: function (status) {
            alert(status["d"])
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function () {
            alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the WebMethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string uploadImgVarianti(string imgBase64)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    context.Response.Write(decodedString);        

    return "ok";
}
```

stackTrace from iis

at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)

sorry for the unindented stack trace but is more readable in this form

Have an idea to save this image with a WebMethod?

P.s. WebMethod is necessary because i need to manipulate image, and do some operation with a database.

Answer (score 2):

It's really not easy to send the content of a file in base64 from JavaScript to a C# Web Api. I can tell you a thing or two about it.

I created a sample app in Visual Studion 2019 that works with respect to the following key points:

In C#:

1. Create a Model Class like this. Notice byte[]. Web Api will transform the base64 string in a byte[] automaticlly (by convention!).

   ```
   namespace WebApplicationForStackOverflow1.Models
   {
       public class ImageFile
       {
           public string Filename { get; set; }
           public byte[] Content { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a Controller like this

   ```
   namespace WebApplicationForStackOverflow1.Controllers
   {
       public class ImageFileController : ApiController
       {
           // POST: api/ImageFile
           public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ImageFile imageFile)
           {
               HttpResponseMessage ret = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, imageFile);
               return ret;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

In JavaScript:

3. Use readAsDataURL() of the FileReader object and use only the Base64 part from the result after ","

   ```
   getBase64: function (file, cb) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = function () {
           console.log(reader.result);//outputs random looking characters for the image
           // Return the result in the callback
           cb(reader.result.split( ",")[1]);
       };
       reader.onerror = function (error) {
           console.log('Error: ', error);
       };
   },
   ```
4. Use JSON.stringify in $.ajax() to make a json text out of the data object and use the correct parameters for the success and error callbacks

   ```
   sendData: function (filename, data) {
       octopus.imgbase64 = data
       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: '/api/ImageFile',
           data: JSON.stringify({
               Filename: filename,
               Content: data
           }),
           success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               alert(textStatus)
           },
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string UploadImage(string base64Image,string ImageName)
{
    string path =Server.MapPath("~/images/");
      if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    path+=ImageName;
    byte[] fileByte = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);
    using (FileStream _FileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, 
   FileAccess.Write))
    {
                _FileStream.Write(fileByte, 0, fileByte.Length);
    }
  return "/images/"+ImageName;

}
```

Comment: same error:{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (132): {base64Image:\u0027����\u0006�Exif\u0000\u0000MM\u0000*...}. I cant write all message because is too long.